# How can I test this distribution?

Tags: self-study, statistical-significance

Say I have 40 people that are sorted into 20 pairs. Out of the 40 people, 20 are A People and 20 are B People.

I want to see if the distribution of A People and B People is random. For example, if it were random, I would expect some pairs to have two A People and some to have two B People. If it were not random, I would expect most pairs to be one A Person and one B Person.

How can I test this? Also, would the test change if the 40 people were 10 A People and 30 B People?

This is for a personal project. Thank you!

Comment: If it is for a personal project, please tell us how far you have gotten. And tag it self-study. Thx.

Comment: I left the question general, but here is my real data: I have 62 people, 25 which are A People and 37 which are B People. I want to know if, in the 31 pairs, A People are non-randomly distributed. In the 31 pairs, 8 have 0 A People, 21 have 1 A Person, and 2 have 2 A People.

Comment: If random you would expect approximately 50% A and B, around 25% A and A and 25% B and B but nonrandom just means a large departure from these percentages. It does not necessarily mean almost all A and B. It would also be non random if almost none of the pairs were A and B as for example if half were A and A and the other half were B and B.

Comment: In asking practical questions here, it is almost always a good idea to _start_ by asking the exact problem at hand, instead of trying to pose a "generalized" problem

Answer (score 1):

Now that we have your actual question, I will try again to give a specific answer. Suppose we have 25 Type 1 people and 37 Type 2 people and put them at random into 31 pairs.

We choose 31 first members of each pair at random without replacement from among the 62; then we randomly choose 31 second members of each pair.

In R this can be done as follows:

```
set.seed(212)  # for reproducibility
pop = c(rep(1, 25), rep(2,37))
perm = sample(perm)  # randomly permute the 62 people
first = perm[1:31];  secnd = perm[32:62]
first; secnd
[1] 1 1 2 2 2 1 2 1 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 2 1 1 2 2 2 1
[1] 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 2 1 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 1 2 1 1 2 2 2 2 1 2
```

Then we count the pairs that have 1-1 or 2-2 matches. We see we have 18 matches out of 31 pairs. (It turns out that the number of matches is always even.)

```
sum(first==secnd)
[1] 18
```

Now we simulate this pairing and counting through a million iterations in order
to approximate the distribution of the number of matches arising from random pairing.

```
set.seed(2019)
pop = c(rep(1, 25), rep(2,37));  m=10^6; x = numeric(m)
for(i in 1:m) {
  perm = sample(pop)
  x[i] = sum(perm[1:31]==perm[32:62]) }
table(x)/10^6
x
       6        8       10       12       14       16       18 
0.000173 0.003591 0.028495 0.110641 0.235683 0.291797 0.212950 
      20       22       24       26       28 
0.091361 0.022099 0.003003 0.000202 0.000005
```

[image]

So it appears that we might reject the null hypothesis of independence at about the 6% level of significance, if
we get 6, 8, 10, 22, 24, 26, 28 or 30 matches. (Or at about the 1% level if we get 6, 8, 24, 26, 28 or 30 matches.)

```
mean(abs(x-16) > 4)
[1] 0.057568
mean(abs(x-16) > 6)
[1] 0.006974
```

*Notes:* (1) A different simulation (with no specified seed or a different one) will give slightly different probabilities, but with a million iterations, probabilities should be accurate to two or three places. (2) You may want to try a combinatorial approach to finding the exact probabilities. (3) Although it didn't show up among a million iterations in the simulation shown, one could clearly get 30 matches as an extremely non-random possibility: 12 pairs with matching 1's and 18 with matching 2's, along with only one pair with a 1 and a 2.